# Site accessible with multiple URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, silex

I'm using the micro framework Silex on my website hosted on a VPS.

So, the site files are in the `/site_name/public_html/` folder but, with Silex, the site must point to the `/site_name/public_html/web/` folder.

In the `public_html` directory, I have the following `.htaccess` file :

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect to https & www
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

    # Redirect incoming URLs to web folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
    RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And, in the `/public_html/web/` folder, the following `.htaccess` :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Redirect incoming URLs to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, everything works fine but my pages are accessible with three different patterns :

1. `example.com/page/` (the one I want to keep)
2. `example.com/web/page/`
3. `example.com/web/index.php/page/`

I have used the meta canonical to avoid duplicate content but I still want these last two options to not exist.

I guess I have something to change in both `.htaccess` files but I can't find what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually remove the `.htaccess` file in the `/web` subdirectory altogether and rewrite directly to `/web/index.php` in the root `.htaccess` file. By having two `.htaccess` files you are seemingly creating extra work. The mod_rewrite directives in the subdirectory will completely override the parent directives (by default), so your canonical HTTPS and www redirects are also being overridden.

(Presumably you had a `RewriteEngine On` directive in the `/web/.htaccess` file?)

Having removed the `/web/.htaccess` file, try something like the following in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web

# Redirect to https & www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

# If /web or /index.php is present at the start of the requested URL then remove it (via redirect)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(?:web|index\.php)/(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]

# Front-controller...
# Internally rewrite all requests to /web/index.php (uses RewriteBase set above)
RewriteRule index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures we only test initial requests and not requests that have been later rewritten.

The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required, unless your site is intended to work without mod_rewrite.

Note that a request like `/web/index.php/page/` would result in two redirects. First to `/index.php/page` then to `/page`. Since this is an edge case I would consider a double redirect to be acceptable.

**UPDATE:** I've removed the "directory" check in the above as this would have prevented the document root (`example.com/`) from being rewritten to the `/web` subdirectory. This would have consequently resulted in a 403 if you didn't have a directory index document (eg. `index.php`) in the document root of your site. (However, requests for `example.com/page/` should have still worked OK.)

Test with 302 (temporary) redirects and only change to 301 (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK - to avoid any caching issues in the browser. Be sure to clear the browser cache before testing.

Comment: I also think that it is better with a single .htaccess file. However, using the code above, I have a 403 Forbidden error... Thank you for your help. Edit: Also, could you please tell me why you changed the https redirection from 301 to 302?

Comment: Ah, is that a 403 for the document root, ie. `example.com/`? You'll need to remove the `RewriteCond` directive that checks that it's not a directory. The 302 is just for testing (sorry, I meant to add a note about that). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still not working... The page is showing but images and styles are not found. example.com/web/ redirects to example.com but example.com/web/index.php redirects to example.com/index.php (404 error). Thank you again for your help.